# Trouble posting in Sub-Category

Tags: sub-menu, posting

On my Main Menu, I have made category called "Blog" and then under that a drop down tab listed "News". I am trying to add a News item in this subcategory, but for some reason keeps positing under Blog, and Leaving "News" blank, any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have created a simple page name News from the Admin and displayed under the Blog Menu. You have to create a page template and use the WordPress loop to display your posts. You can use this code in your page template and select templates when you publish the page.

```
$args = array(    
    'post_type'       => 'post',  
    'order'           => 'DESC',  
);   

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );   
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();   
    php the_title();  
    the_excerpt(__('(more…)'));     
endwhile;
```

You can pass more parameters to filter your loop as per your need.

Comment: I'm still not understanding correctly :-(